# System.ArgumentNullException occurred in Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.dll

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to develop an ASP MVC application and tried to created a simple Authentication which always works when creating a new project on my computer. 
Now, i have a solution that was created on another machine which throws an exception when being run on my computer.

Here is the code that's throwing the exception

```
public IdentitySignInManager(BusinessModuleList modules, IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager)
        : base(modules.Get<IdentityUserManager<TUser, TDataAccessModule, TDataContext>>(), authenticationManager)
    {
        Prerequisites = new List<Prerequisite>();
        Modules = modules;
    }
```

The above method is inside the IdentitySignInManager.cs file which looks like the following

```
 public class IdentitySignInManager<TUser, TDataAccessModule, TDataContext> : SignInManager<TUser, String>, IBusinessModule
    where TUser: UserBase
    where TDataAccessModule : IdentityDataAccessModule<TUser, TDataContext>
    where TDataContext : IdentityDataContext<TUser>
{

    #region Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// The module list.
    /// </summary>
    public BusinessModuleList Modules { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The prerequisites of the normal functionality of the module.
    /// </summary>
    public List<Prerequisite> Prerequisites { get; private set; }

    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes the new instance of IdentitySignInManager.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="modules">The module list.</param>
    /// <param name="authenticationManager">The authentication manager.</param>
    public IdentitySignInManager(BusinessModuleList modules, IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager)
        : base(modules.Get<IdentityUserManager<TUser, TDataAccessModule, TDataContext>>(), authenticationManager)
    {
        Prerequisites = new List<Prerequisite>();
        Modules = modules;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes the new instance of IdentitySignInManager. Supressed.
    /// </summary>
    private IdentitySignInManager(UserManager<TUser, String> userManager, IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager)
        : base(userManager, authenticationManager)
    {
    }

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates the claims based identity from the user.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="user">The user.</param>
    /// <param name="authenticationType">The authentication type. Ther default is "ApplicationCookie".</param>
    /// <returns>The claims based identity.</returns>
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> CreateUserIdentityAsync(TUser user, String authenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie)
    {
        return await Modules.Get<IdentityUserManager<TUser, TDataAccessModule, TDataContext>>().CreateIdentityAsync(user, authenticationType);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// If disposing, calls dispose on the Context. Always nulls out the Context. Also disposes the Modules.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">True to dispose managed resources, false to not to dispose them.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            Modules.Dispose();
            Modules = null;
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #endregion

}
```

The exception it throws is the following

An exception of type:

> 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.dll but was not handled in user code

If i click F5 and continue with the code, it shows me this error on the browser

Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: userManager

Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.SignInManager`2..ctor(UserManager`2 userManager, IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager)
   at Core.BusinessModules.Users.Modules.IdentitySignInManager`3..ctor(BusinessModuleList modules, IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager) in d:\projects\payroll\Trunk\Sources\Core.BusinessModules.Users\Modules\IdentitySignInManager.cs:line 50
   at PR.Web.Application.Common.Modules.AppSignInManager..ctor(BusinessModuleList modules, IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager) in d:\projects\payroll\Trunk\Sources\PR.Web.Application\Common\Modules\AppSignInManager.cs:line 30
   at PR.Web.Application.Common.Web.OWinContextCallbacks.CreateBusinessModules(IdentityFactoryOptions`1 options, IOwinContext context) in d:\projects\payroll\Trunk\Sources\PR.Web.Application\Common\Web\OWinContextCallbacks.cs:line 37
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.IdentityFactoryProvider`1.Create(IdentityFactoryOptions`1 options, IOwinContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.IdentityFactoryMiddleware`2.d__0.MoveNext()

On the startup.cs i have the following code, among others

```
 private static void ConfigureAuthentication(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
    {

        appBuilder.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<AppUserManager, User>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => manager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie))
            }
        });

        appBuilder.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

    }
```

The exception is thrown immediately after it finishes executing the above code.

How would i fix this error?

Comment: Where is the method with the parameter name of "userManager"?

Comment: Which code\method is called when it finishes executing configureAuthentication method?? Probably, you should attach debugger. VS will show the source code which is causing the problem.

Comment: The execution is thrown immediately after the end bracket of the ConfigureAuthentication method. I used breakpoints and it threw the exception as soon as it got to the end bracket.

Comment: Perhaps the message is correct and you passed a null value as a  parameter? Where is the rest of the exception, especially its call stack? "After the end bracket" means it *doesn't* occur in `ConfigureAuthentication`. Most likely, no UserManager was registered so IdentitySignInManager (which *does* require a userManager) can't be created

Comment: it happens after the ConfigureAuthentication is finished. I have also posted the stack trace from the browser.